# Probability of finite intersection of sets

Tags: probability-theory

i have a couple of questions regarding this claim (i have already proove it):

$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}) \geq 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_{i}^c)$

Where $A^{c}$ is the complement of A with respect the sample space (we can call it $\Omega$, where $P(\Omega) = 1$).

What's the intuition behind this? I have drawn a Venn diagramm, but i can't conclude nothing interesting.

Another question, this claim is also true if we let $n$ tends to $\infty$ right?

Thank's a lot.

Comment: May be more obvious on taking complements?

Answer (score 1):

Every outcome that is *not* in the intersection on the left must be in one of the $A_i^\complement$s.

So if you subtract the probability volume of each of the $A_i^\complement$ from $1$, you're going to have each of those outcomes handled at least one.

And yes, this should be true for $n\to\infty$ too -- the worst thing that can happen is that you end up subtracting infinity on the right-hand side, but that just makes the inequality *very* true.